# C++ code execution time depends on code structre

Tags: c++

I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPknaBO3Dhk&index=1&list=PL3sGw6DVKZGhluBfzgmnemANInhPHMEl8) great youtube tutorial and in one of the slides I saw something I didn't understand. Why is this happening? Is this compiler related?

Version #1 looks like this:

```
const int N = 5000;
float a [N*N];

for (int x=0; x<n; ++x)
     for(int y=0; y<N; ++y)
          sum+=a[x+y*N];
```

and takes about 239.4ms to execute.

And version #2 looks like this:

```
const int N = 5000;
float a [N*N];

for (int y=0; y<n; ++y)
     for(int x=0; x<N; ++x)
          sum+=a[x+y*N];
```

and takes about 79.5ms to execute.
Why is this happening?

Comment: @user202729 well I did not linked my question to another site, just added a refernce to the actual video for credit, meaning i'm not the owner of the content. but thanks for your note.

Comment: changed it, noted to myself.

Answer (score 5):

The second example demonstrates better data locality since it accesses elements in the same row. Basically it performs sequential memory read, while first example jumps over `sizeof(float) * N` bytes on each iteration putting extra stress on CPU cache / memory.

Comment: Can it be that the compiler optimizes the value of the multiplication, so in the second case it does not have to reevaluate the value of y*N on every loop iteration?

Comment: @kangaro0 Actually I think that multiplication can be optimized (by converting into addition) in both cases. In first case it will probably be just `+ N` and `+ 1` in second case.

Comment: Accessing contiguous memory is always faster. As @VTT said, data locality!